How to download and decompress a .gz file in react native using expo and type script
I am trying to figure out how can I download a .gz file in react native using expo and decompress it so I can read the file within.
This is the file that I want to download "http://files.tmdb.org/p/exports/movie_ids_12_23_2024.json.gz"
Can anyone advise what is the best solution to this ?
I have tried to look on the internet couldn't find anything and co-pilot and all the solutions were not working.
Compressed file is about 20MB and decompressed about 100MB. When I used any of the co-pilot solutions the app mostly just crashes.
One example I have shown below. The error I get with it is
ERROR  Error inflating chunk: incorrect header check
ERROR  Error downloading or unpacking: incorrect header check
export const downloadAndUnpack = async () => { const downloadUri = 'http://files.tmdb.org/p/exports/movie_ids_12_23_2024.json.gz'; // URL of the .gz file 

const unpackedPath = ${FileSystem.documentDirectory}example.txt;

try {
  console.log('Fetching the .gz file...');
  const response = await fetch(downloadUri);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch file: ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  console.log('Blob fetched. Converting to ArrayBuffer...');
  const blob = await response.blob();

  // Convert Blob to ArrayBuffer using FileReader
  const arrayBuffer = await new Promise<ArrayBuffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log('FileReader onload');
      resolve(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);
    };
    reader.onerror = () => {
      console.log('FileReader onerror');
      reject(reader.error);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });

  const gzContent = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  console.log('ArrayBuffer converted to Uint8Array');

  // Process the data in smaller chunks
  const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks
  let offset = 0;
  let decompressedData = '';

  console.log('Starting decompression...');
  while (offset < gzContent.length) {
    const chunk = gzContent.subarray(offset, Math.min(offset + chunkSize, gzContent.length));
    try {
      decompressedData += pako.inflate(chunk, { to: 'string' });
      console.log(`Processed chunk from ${offset} to ${Math.min(offset + chunkSize, gzContent.length)}`);
    } catch (inflateError) {
      console.error('Error inflating chunk:', inflateError);
      throw inflateError;
    }
    offset += chunkSize;
  }

  console.log('Decompression complete. Saving data...');
  await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(unpackedPath, decompressedData);
  console.log('Unpacked file saved to:', unpackedPath);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error downloading or unpacking:', error);
}
};

